# Prove a matrix is invertible

Tags: matrices

The $2 \times 2$ matrix ${A}$ satisfies
$A^2 - 4 {A} - 7{I} = {0},$
where ${I}$ is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. Prove that ${A}$ is invertible.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: use the definition of invertible matrices

Answer (score 8):

$$
A^2-4A-7I = 0\\
A(A-4I) = 7I\\
A\left(\frac{A-4I}{7}\right) = I
$$

A matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if there exist ${A}^{-1}$ such that:

$$
A{A}^{-1}= I
$$

So from our previous answer we conclude that:

$$
{A}^{-1} = \frac{A-4I}{7}
$$

So ${A}^{-1}$ exists, hence $A$ is invertible.

Note:

if you had the value of $A$ you would only calculate its determinant and check if it is non zero.

$\det(A)\quad \neq \quad 0\Longleftrightarrow A\quad \textrm{is}\quad \textrm{invertible}$

Comment: Nice answer. Saves me the work to answer this OP. +1 I made a small edit...

Comment: Ah thanks, always glad to help ^^

Comment: Tip for $\LaTeX$, use $\backslash\textrm{det}$, and $\backslash\textrm{left}($ $\backslash\textrm{right})$... Good Luck!

Comment: Oh thanks that will help write more organised answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

$${1\over7}(A-4I)A={1\over 7}(A^2-4A)={1\over 7}{7I}=I\\
A{1\over7}(A-4I)={1\over 7}(A^2-4A)={1\over 7}{7I}=I$$

Answer (score 1):

Given that $A$ satisfies $A^2−4A−7I=0$ (use Cayley- Hamilton theorem). Let $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ be eigen value of $A$.

$\gamma_1+\gamma_2=4$.

$\gamma_1\gamma_2=-7$. Therefore $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are non zero.
Hence $A$ is invertible matrix